# How to print the error message returned by service call?

Tags: tcl

When I run this the below TCL code, I get the successful output for first service call ie.

> "Result = xyz"

However, the second service call executes the service and the service returns an error, because of that we enter in the if loop however it doesnt print the error message returned by service call and it just prints an empty string.

```
proc serviceCall {prefix} {
    return [mimic.list :prefix $prefix]
}

puts "###### Svc Call With prefix set to Single Char ################## \n"
if {[catch {puts "Result = [serviceCall \"l\"]"} errmsg]} {
   puts "ErrorMsg: $errmsg\n"
}

puts "\n\n###### Svc Call With prefix set to space ################## \n"
if {[catch {puts "Result = [serviceCall \"\ \" ]"} errmsg]} {
   puts "ErrorMsg: $errmsg\n"
}
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with the `mimic.list` command, but I can't say more than that without knowing how it was defined exactly.

Comment: What is an `if loop`? Pls. print  (from an actual implementation of `mimic.list`) and post the content of the dictionary of return options: `catch {serviceCall "l"} msg opts; puts opts=$opts`?

Comment: pls. print `opts` when populated in your actual script, not when running my exemplary snippet from my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [`try`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/try.htm) instead of `catch`, and use less backslashes (unless you indend to send a 3 character string with literal quotes to the proc)

```
puts "###### Svc Call With prefix set to Single Char ################## \n"
try {
    puts "Result = [serviceCall "l"]"
} on error errmsg {
    puts "ErrorMsg: $errmsg"
}
```

Comment: Awesome sir thanks. Could you please also tell explain why in my code catch statement is not printing the error message correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Probably the escaped quotes in the command substitution in the quoted string